# How to apply tracked changes to specific sections of a document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a VBA macro that attaches a review slip at the end of a document that is to be reviewed by coworkers and management.  The section of the document where the review slip is attached is protected for filling in forms.  I also have enabled tracked changes, but it is applied to the entire document.

My problem arises when people enter values on the review slip (e.g., sign off on their review of the routed document), tracked changes makes a mess of the review slip.

Management does desire to print out this form once the document has completed the review and editing process, which is one reason it was appended to the document.

Similar to how I can restrict editing in a portion of the document to only filling in forms,
(e.g., `ActiveDocument.Sections(ActiveDocument.Sections.Count).ProtectedForForms = True`)
I want to only enable tracked changes for all but the last section of the document.

Or, is there a way to automagically accept all changes only within the last section of the document?

Comment: Your approach is fundamentally wrong as you have incorporated the sign off form into the document itself.  If I were doing this task I would use document variables,custom document properties or a task paneto store the names/inputs of the reviewers and then just use a standard VBA form to manage the signoffs, with the relevant button to launch the form being in the Review Tab.

Comment: Undoubtedly I have approached this incorrectly, but I needed to revise an existing process with limited available time with admittedly little talent.  If/when I have time, I will look into revising the process to follow what you have suggested, but for now I have to live with this.  Thanks, Dale

Answer (score 0):

You could use Word's SelectionChange event to test which Section the user is working in and turn off track-changes if the selection is in the last Section. The actual code would be:

```
Private Sub oApp_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
With ActiveDocument
  .TrackRevisions = (.Range(0, Sel.Start).Sections.Count <> .Sections.Count)
End With
End Sub
```

However, you can't just use the above code on its own. For implementation, see: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/AppClassEvents.htm

Comment: Thank you macropod.  I was really hoping something like that would work but everything I see for .TrackRevisions is that it is boolean.  I do appreciate the suggestion, though.

Comment: «everything I see for .TrackRevisions is that it is boolean» - which is precisely what the code I posted employs. Did you *try* it? I suspect not.